# Building Android and iOS Apps with Cordova.js in an Existing Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, cordova, build, laravel-mix

I have an existing Laravel project that utilizes Cordova.js for Android and iOS platform applications. Now, I need guidance on how to create builds for Android and iOS platforms and how to integrate Cordova commands into my Laravel Mix project. Any advice or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated.

[Corodva build issue (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSmxs.png)

I have tried different Cordova commands:
Like
`cordova platform add ios cordova platform add android cordova build`

But these are showing results as attached screenshot.